# AngularJs : ng-option of select statement not getting filtered with ng-model of other select statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Hi I am doing something which might not be a good practice in Angular Js.

here is my html code:

```
<div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="dealership">Dealership:</label>
                <select data-placeholder="Select Dealers" class="chosen" id="select1" chosen="SelectedDealerRank" style="width: 100%;" ng-model="SelectedDealerRank" ng-options="SelectedDealerRank as SelectedDealerRank.Dealership for SelectedDealerRank in AllDealers" ng-change="search();"></select></div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="staff-member">Staff member:</label>
                <!--<input type="text" ng-model="staffquery" style="height:25px; width:130px;" ng-change="searchallstaffmembers()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">-->
                <select data-placeholder="Select Staff member" class="chosen" chosen="staffMemberRank" ng-model="staffMemberRank" ng-options="staffMemberRank as staffMemberRank.StaffMemberName for staffMemberRank in  d2filteredstaffmembers" ng-change="" style="width: 100%;"></select>
              </div>
            </div>
```

on ng-change search method gets called....

search method

```
    $scope.search = function () {
    $scope.d2filteredstaffmembers = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredstaffmembers.length; i++) {
        if (!$scope.SelectedDealerRank.DealerID.toString() || $scope.SelectedDealerRank.DealerID.toString() == 0) {
            $scope.d2filteredstaffmembers.push($scope.filteredstaffmembers[i]);
        }
        else if ($scope.filteredstaffmembers[i].DealerID.toString() == $scope.SelectedDealerRank.DealerID.toString()) {
            if ($scope.filteredstaffmembers[i] != null || $scope.filteredstaffmembers[i] != undefined) {
                $scope.d2filteredstaffmembers.push($scope.filteredstaffmembers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
 };
```

after call of method i am setting d2filteredstaffmembers the source of staff member to new values but it's not showing any changes.

any idea?

Comment: Did you check with a breakpoint to be sure that search() is working as expected?

Comment: Yes I have checked with breakpoint. New values are pushed but not reflected on ng - options of select.

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, I would suggest you to reproduce it in a fiddle or a plnker. It would be easier for us to solve.